# Auto incrementing from two different points on the same table?

Tags: database, database-design

Each customer has an ID. For every new customer it's incremented by 1.

My company is wanting to start selling to a new type of customer (lets call it customer B), and have their ID start at 30k.

Is this a poor design? Our system has an option to set the customer type, so there is no need for this. We're not expected to reach this number for our other type of customers until 2050 (it's currently at 10k).

I'm trying to convince them that this is a bad idea... It also doesn't help the third party trying to implement this is ok with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confusing the **technical** and **functional keys** is the really bad idea. Technical keys are designed to be unchanged, to maintain the referential integrity and to speed up the joins. Technical keys are also to avoid of exposing at the application level (i.e. in the screen forms).

Functional keys are visible to application users and may be a subject to change accordingly to new requirements.

Other bad idea is to use number parts to separate data partitions (customer groups in your case). The character code having a complex structure like a social security number is a more strong and scalable solution (however it's a sort of denormalization, too).

The recommended solution is to have a technical ID as an auto-incremental number but also add a functional customer code.

Answer (score 1):

If the identifier is customer-facing or business user-facing then it makes sense to design it with readability and usability in mind. Most people find it very natural work with identification schemes that have information encoded within them: think of phone numbers, vehicle licence plate numbers, airline flight numbers. There is evidence that a well structured identification scheme can improve usability and reduce the rate of errors in day to day use. You could expect that a well-designed "meaningful" identification scheme will result in fewer errors than an arbitrary incrementing number with no identifiable features.

There's nothing inherently wrong with doing this. Whether it makes sense in your business context depends a lot on how the number will be used. Technically speaking it isn't difficult to build multiple independent sequences, e.g. using the SEQUENCE feature in SQL. You may want to consider including other features as well, like check digits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer -- sadly we do not have the freedom to implement some of these ideas. In our scenario, we are stuck with the table design. I would also be worried about running out of customer type A identification numbers for the sake of readability.